# PHP problem in IE "supplied argument is not a valid stream resource"

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I set up a thing so that, from various places on my website, I can link to a page called "linktothis.php" which will include a link to the referring page.  It works fine in firefox, but IE seems to give it trouble and it tells me:

```
Warning: fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /usr/local/apache/sites/nextadvisor/linktothis.php on line 19
```

(line 19 is the 4th line below)

```
<?php
$filesource = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$a = fopen($filesource,"r"); //fopen("html_file.html","r");
$string = fread($a,1024);
if (eregi("<linkto>(.*)</linkto>", $string, $out)) {
    $outdata = $out[1];
}
//echo $outdata;
$outdatapart = explode( " " , $outdata);
echo $part[0];
if (empty($outdata)) if (eregi("<title>(.*)</title>", $string, $out)) {
    $outdata = $out[1];
}
//echo $outdata;
$outdatapart = explode( " " , $outdata);
echo $part[0];
?>
```

What do I need to switch so that this will work in IE?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your IE does not provide the referring page to your script? Try a var__dump($_SERVER) to verify that.

Comment: It appears that that's the case.  What sort of workarounds are there for this?

Comment: There is no workaround for this. The browser won't tell your php script where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

It should be issue with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`. Try to echo this variable in Ie and see what it contains.

Comment: It won't echo.  When I echo it, it turns up blank.